# Why eigenvalues are greater than 1 in factor analysis?

Tags: factor-analysis

Why we take eigenvalue greater than 1 in factor analysis to retain factors?
 And how can we decide which variables are to be chosen as factors?

Comment: Is this about PCA or FA?

Answer (score 9):

Using eigenvalues > 1 is only *one* indication of how many factors to retain. Other reasons include the scree test, getting a reasonable proportion of variance explained and (most importantly) substantive sense.

That said, the rule came about because the average eigenvalue will be 1, so > 1 is "higher than average".

On your second question: Are you asking how to know how many factors (latent variables) to retain? Or are you asking about which observed variables to retain?

If the former, see above and see any book on factor analysis. If the latter, each factor is a linear combination of *all* the observed variables (although some contribute very little).

Comment: Great answer, but regarding the last point, observed variables are linear combinations of the relevant factors and the error term - factors are not a linear combination of the observed variables (instead they refect the variation shared amongst them). Factors can only be a linear combination of the observed variables if you "flip the arrows" i.e. use a "causal indicator model" see --> http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19266502

Answer (score 0):

I came across a very simple and interesting explanation for this eigenvalue>1 criterion:

> ... .Those with eigenvalues less than 1.00 are not considered to be stable. They account for less variability than does a single variable and are not retained in the analysis. In this sense, you end up with fewer factors than original number of variables.
>   (Girden, 2001)

I paraphrase like so: **because you don't want to end up with more or equal number of factors as the number of your variables is. When a factor has an eigen value less than 1.00, in a sense it has less than one variable in it.**

**References**
Girden, E. R. (2001). Evaluating research articles from start to finish. Thousand Oaks, Calif., Sage Publications.

Comment: "Number of variables" and size of eigenvalue do not have anything to do with each other.  Careful accounts of PCA do not make blanket statements like the one you quote, because which components to retain depends on more than just their eigenvalues (as suggested by Peter Flom's answer).  It is impossible to have more factors (components) than variables anyway, even when you include the components with the very smallest eigenvalues, so your paraphrasing cannot possibly be an accurate representation of the quotation.